# Is checking for first character before doing strcmp useful?

Tags: c, string, strcmp

which of the following is more efficient :

```
if (strcmp(str1,str2) != 0) {
...
}
```

OR

```
if (str1[0]!=str2[0] && strcmp(str1,str2) !=0 ) {
...
}
```

If `str2` is always unique and there can be multiple str1.

Comment: you would check `*s1==*s2 && !strcmp(s1+1, s2+1)` otherwise you are doing redundant checks of [0]

Comment: Run the test and see for yourself. May be you can feed us the benchmark data. Actually, it all depends on the type of data (how huge) you have.

Comment: @tech Your code is a buffer overrun

Comment: @DavidHeffernan only if one of the strings is not known to be of length >0 which is not always the case.  A typical usage is comparing a variable to a known constant i.e. strcmp("--help",s) where that would be safe, but if you are comparing 2 _variables_ then definitely, yes it would need an extra check for null strings `!(*s1|*s2)` /*true iff both strings are null*/  I have benchmarked this in the past for a large binary search of sorted constants; the additional first char comparison improved performance by ~10% in that non-typical scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of second version as `strcmp` is usually implemented very smartly to compare multiple characters at once.

In second version, because of short-circuit property of `&&`, you may save a function call. You should benchmark both version for your requirements to get the correct idea.

But my suggestion still is, there is no need of version 2 `(str1[0]!=str2[0] && strcmp(str1,str2) !=0 )` proposed by you unless `strcmp` is proved as bottleneck (in profiling result) for your requirement and there are evidences that version 2 performs better.

Comment: <sarcasm>because calls and jumps are free</sarcasm> ... the whole point of the first letter comparison it to provide an inline fast path ... for gcc and constant strings the first version will optimize better, but for general use it helps to have a cheap fast path as in the other example

Comment: @technosaurus: You're assuming that `strcmp` is a call, not inlined/intrinsic. If comparing the first character and then branching is the right thing, `strcmp` can be inlined to do just that.

Comment: How does `(str1[0]!=str2[0] && str1[0] != '\0' && strcmp(str1,str2) !=0 )` prevent UB in `(str1[0]!=str2[0] && strcmp(str1,str2) !=0 )`?  It does prevent UB in `*s1==*s2 && !strcmp(s1+1, s2+1)` as noted by @David Heffernan, but OP did not propose that.

Answer (score 1):

```
strcmp(str1,str2) !=0
```

checks the first character and returns if they are not equal. So you need not exclusively check for

```
str1[0]!=str2[0].
```

Your `str1[0]!=str2[0]` does the same thing what `strcmp(str1,str2)` does in the first check.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` starts comparing the first character of each string. If they are equal to each other, it continues with the following pairs until the characters differ or until a terminating null-character is reached.

So for second case it seems no meaning for extra condition to check first character of string.

because `strcmp` already done `(str1[0]!=str2[0])` it.

Comment: Many implementations may choose not compare character by character but by comparing multiple characters at once. (4 or 8 characters at once are common)

Answer (score 1):

As @Abhineet suggests "test and see for yourself".

`if (strcmp(str1,str2) != 0)` and `if ((str1[0] != str2[0]) && strcmp(str1,str2) !=0 )` are *functionally* the same when each is passed a C string.  This, of course, is a requirement, else, why compare performance?

C does not focus on specifying performance, so should this approach work faster with a given compiler on a given machine, it may be worse with the next version of the compiler or some compiler option change or a different string data set.

But in my experience, making code with heavily string usage on multiple platforms, this *trick* did improve performance in select machines and did not significantly slow others.  Your results may vary.

As with any linear improvements in performance, slight code tweaks in heavily used code need deep understanding of the target machine to *know* if is *always* faster.

Typically, using your programming time to think about other approaches can reap far larger performance improvements.

1) hash codes
  2) unique strings need only pointer compare
  3) Other "string" structures